# Make Application available via Facebook only

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've an application at http://noupei.com/other/createfbapps/index.php and I want this application to be available only via facebook at https://apps.facebook.com/takeflights/.

In short, I want the application to be available only via facebook. Does someone know how to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible. Have a look at the following example:

https://component-factory.com/component/fbhelper/demo/

It will redirect the user each time he is calling the application out of facebook. The Trick is to handle with the Referer's, Facebook Linter calls etc.